# How to block taking screenshot for android app

Tags: android, android-webview, screenshot, epub3

I am working on an android app where my requirement is to disable the screenshot functionality for the entire app

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }
```

I have used the above code to block the screenshot, partially it is working fine. As my code contains WebView to show the epub3(HTML + CSS + JS) contents on an app it is not specifically restricting that content only, it is allowing taking a screenshot for that content

please help
thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you showing the `WebView`? Is it in the same window on which you are adding `FLAG_SECURE`?

Comment: hi, @CommonsWare no, for this we are using different activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for this we are using different activity

Then you are going to need to add `FLAG_SECURE` to that activity's window as well, as well as any other activity that you wish to secure. `FLAG_SECURE` works on a per-window basis, and each activity gets its own window.

Comment: so is that like, how many activity we have that many FLAG_SECURE we have to set ??

Comment: @PiyushJiwane: Yes. Each activity will need to use the code snippet from your question to set `FLAG_SECURE` for that activity's window.

Answer (score 2):

Add each activity on below onCreate()

```
 this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```